# Which pattern to use to parse 2012-10-05T14:33:24.935Z

Tags: java, android

What pattern should I use to parse `2012-10-05T14:33:24.935Z` String into `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 4):

This should work `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: 'String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String sampleDateStr = "2012-10-05T14:33:24.935Z";
 ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date sampleDate = sdf.parse(sampleDateStr, pos);'
sampleDate is null

Comment: You should replace `Z` in the date string with a valid time zone, like `GMT+5:30`